# Webhook Service Provider or Project

Tags: rest, messaging, webhooks

Does anyone know of a service provider or a project that will provide me with webhook functionality?  Sure it's just a matter of sending a HTTP/S POST, but it should be implemented with a queue for durability and also some sort of retry logic.  I'd prefer not to implement this if there is a project, package, or service that provides this.

I did find [pubsubhubbub](http://code.google.com/p/pubsubhubbub/) but that's just a reference application and protocol specification.  A production implementation of this would be great if it were available.

Comment: I'm going to be looking for the same thing in a few weeks.  What technology are you focusing on?

Answer (score 0):

Amazon's [SNS](http://aws.amazon.com/sns/) allows both http and https, email, etc

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is old, but www.inflectus.com provides a managed webhook service.

Disclaimer -  I am involved with the company